# Check if item is included in an array or hash

Tags: ruby

Is it possible to something like this in Ruby

```
if @subscription.state = ['trail', 'active']
   #Do something 
end
```

Should be self explanatory.

Comment: [http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.0/Array.html) Know it. Love it. Live it.

Comment: Did you do a [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[ruby][array]find) for this, or try reading the documentation for Array or Enumerable before asking? It might seem harsh, but we expect you to have done your homework before asking. This question is too easily answered for you to have done much work.

Comment: Yes i did, Im sorry I'm a NOOB, didn't know what to search for. Is this forum only for individuals that know what they are doing? I think not, if it was, there wouldn't be much need for a forum like this! Think it's a bit ridiculous that my question is getting down votes, but everyone is free to spend their time the way the want. Will try even harder next time to find it my-self so I don't offend you guys that know what you are doing...

Comment: How could I know to search for "[ruby][array]find"???

Comment: @andkjaer, If you restate your problem in general terms, you'd have some excellent terms for your search. In this case, it would have been "How can I determine if a value exists in an array of values in ruby". Try it :)

Comment: I hope somebody gets the Reversal badge out of this question

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `include?` method of ruby's `Array`

```
if ['trail', 'active'].include?(@subscription.state)
  #do something
end
```

Answer (score 7):

Maybe:

```
['trail', 'active'].include?(@subscription.state)
```

Comment: Not "maybe", definitely ;-)

Comment: Haha true, that was because I wasn't sure for the question

Answer (score 0):

Try [Array#include](http://rdoc.info/stdlib/core/1.9.3/Array#include%3F-instance_method) to check this.

```
if ['trail', 'active'].include? @subscription.state
    #Do something 
end
```

I highly suggest reading the [pickaxe book](http://pragprog.com/book/ruby/programming-ruby), as this is a basic Ruby question.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use : [`Enum#any?`](http://www.rubydoc.info/stdlib/core/Enumerable#any%3F-instance_method)

```
@subscription = false
#=> false
[true,false].any? {|x| x == @subscription }
#=> true
@subscription = true
#=> true
[true,false].any? {|x| x == @subscription }
#=> true
@subscription = 15
#=> 15
[true,false].any? {|x| x == @subscription }
#=> false
if [true,false].any? {|x| x == @subscription } then
 p "hi"
else
 p "hello"
end
#"hello"
#=> "hello"
```